# Springboot can't find static index.html

Tags: spring-boot

I'm new to spring boot and for context I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/webrtc.

I've set up an index.html file under `src/main/resources/public/index.html` but when I run my server, I get a 404 error.

I've tried to copy it to the following directories to see if one of them would pick it up:

- `src/main/resources/resources`
- `src/main/resources/static`
- `src/main/resources/public`

No luck with any of them.

I also added thymeleaf to the build with no luck there and started to get the following error:

```
 Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
```

Following this I copied the index.html to: `src/main/resources/templates` also with no luck.

My main class is:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class SignalServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SignalServer.class, args);
    }

}
```

And I wasn't sure if I needed to do this but I added a controller here after trying other things:

```java
@Controller
public class RootController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String root() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

I'm completely lost at this point so any help / suggestions is appreciated.

**Note:** I'm using Bazel for my build system in case that makes any difference to the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: didi you tried with view resolver

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ResourceConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private static final String[] resources = {
            "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "classpath:/META-INF/resources/"};

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations(resources);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`forward:`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-redirecting-forward-prefix):

```
@Controller
public class RootController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String root() {
        return "forward:index.html";
    }
}
```

, and create static resource `src/main/resources/static/index.html`.

(You can also use [some directories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content) instead of `/static`.)